# Ubuntu 14.04 Gnome background out of focus on external 1920x1080 monitor?

Tags: gnome, multiple-monitors, resolution

I've got an external monitor (Samsung 24 inch), and when I try and set a background on gnome, on the monitor it displays slightly blurry. As far as I am aware it's not an issue with the image itself. The odd thing is the background is perfectly in focus when I press the windows key to bring up the menu view.

Answer (score 0):

That's a monitor setting (thus external hardware, thus off-topic here).  Just a small hint before closing this as off-topic: Go to the settings in the monitor itself and try different "refresh rates" aka "scan rates" until it works.